# How do I access a variable inside another method?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I access the variable set in a Setter from within another Setter? Have tried just using $unit but I get a $unit not defined error. Is my problem that I should be trying to do this somewhere else and not from within a setter method? Have spent the last 6 hours trying to do this but I just can't seem to understand it.

The inital variable $unit is set from within a form.

```
public function setUnit($unit)
{
    $this->unit = $unit;

    return $unit;
}
public function getUnit()
{
    return $this->unit;
}
public function setSize($size)
{
    $unit =  <- I wish this to be what it is set as in "public function setUnit($unit)

    $this->size = $size = new Mass($size, $unit);
    $this->size = $size->toUnit('mg');

    return $this;
}
```

I'm using symfony2.3.11

**- EDIT -**

Ok so I followed --'s suggestion which does fix my original question... but now. My form is building this:

```
             ->add('unit', 'choice', array(
'choices'   => array(
    'gram'   => 'gram',
    'kg' => 'Kg',
    'mg'   => 'Mg',
    'oz'   => 'Oz',
    'lb'   => 'Lb',
),
```

Which I was hoping would send the measures to the $unit variable which could then be used by newMass($unit) but I am now receiving

"Unknown unit of measure ($unit)"

I know that all these measures are supported however because when I type them directly into new Mass($size, 'mg'); It works fine.

The original code supplied by the creator looks like this:

```
  $height = new Length(6.16, 'feet');
  echo $height->toUnit('m');
```

And the size variable is working... I really don't understand why the measures are not being sent as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete 
`$unit =  <- I wish this to be what it is set as in "public function setUnit($unit)`
Use in the line below:
`$this->size = new Mass($size, $this->unit);`

Comment: I think your answer has fixed my initial issue however it's created a new one. I will edit my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Make unit as global variable. I dont know symphony syntax (I am php dev) but it could be 
inside the class declare public / private or protected variable. then access from any function inside that class.

Comment: It is defined as a private variable earlier in the document but this is how symfony forces you to make entities.